# c malloc prevent buffer overflow

Tags: c, malloc, buffer-overflow

```
char *host;

host = malloc(64 * sizeof(char)); /* spazio per 64 caratteri */
memset(host,0x00,host[63]);
```

I have a doubt: pointer can be seen as an "array"??
With the above code am i putting NULL into the 64 byte? (to prevent buffer overflow)

Comment: Use `memset(host, 0, 64)` - `memset()` wants a size as the third parameter what you're passing there is uninitialized data (so, nonsense in other words).

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 and `0x00` is a rather sophisticated representation of good old `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your code was correct (see @Dietrich's answer), it doesn't prevent buffer overflow.  I can do this:

```
strcpy(host, "A very large string that's definitely a lot longer than 64 characters, so it will cause you a great deal of misery");
```

Comment: so the best way to protect it is to do this:

Comment: if((strlen(host)+1) > 64){
  fprintf(stderr,"\n--> ERRORE: buffer overflow\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }

Comment: @polslinux: No, that won't do anything useful.  Once you've done the `strcpy`, it's already too late!

Comment: so what can i do to ""prevent a strcpy""??

Comment: @polslinux: Nothing, other than check beforehand that the source string is smaller than the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer can be seen as an array, in C.  However, your code is wrong.

Correct version:

```
char *host;
host = malloc(64);   // sizeof(char) == 1, guaranteed by the standard
if (!host) abort();  // malloc can return NULL if it fails
host[63] = '\0';     // put NUL byte into the last element of array
```

When you run `memset(host, 0x00, host[63])`, it passes the value stored in `host[63]` as the *length* to memset.  This is an error, since `host` is uninitialized, `host[63]` is garbage and you should not pass garbage to `memset`.  If you are very lucky, your program will crash immediately.  If you are unlucky, it will not.

Putting the `\0` byte into the last slot of `host` does not avoid most buffer overflows.  Most different types of buffer overflows need to be handled on an individual basis so there is no "one way" to prevent them.

Buffer overflows are a class of programming mistakes, and like most classes of mistakes, there are a lot of ways to make them.  Each different buffer overflow is just a piece of incorrect code that needs to be fixed.

**Terminology note:** I prefer using `NULL` to refer to the invalid pointer named "NULL" in C, and `NUL` to refer to the zero byte in an ASCII string.  E.g.,

```
// Initialize ptr to a NULL ptr...
char *ptr;
ptr = NULL;
ptr = 0; // equivalent to above

ptr = xmalloc(15);
// Set *ptr to the NUL byte...
*ptr = '\0';
*ptr = 0; // equivalent to above
```

Comment: "A pointer can be seen as an array" - because a pointer can point to the first element of an array, and hence "represents" the array.

Comment: Also, perhaps, say something about NULL vs 0.

Comment: `NULL` is not a invalid pointer. By valid pointer C means either a pointer to an object or a null pointer.

Comment: @DietrichEpp; My concern was that "[…]i putting NULL into the 64 byte[…]" could be some misunderstanding about NULL. To quote Peter van der Linden: "The ASCII character with the bit pattern of zero is termed a "NUL". The special pointer value that means the pointer points nowhere is "NULL". The two terms are not interchangeable in meaning."

Comment: Thanks to all :) you were very exhaustive :) i'm a newbie in C...and you've seen it xD

Comment: @polslinux: If malloc fail it return NULL, so `if(!host) abort();` would become `if (!NULL) abort();` or "if malloc failed abort".